# Android - Send imageView to X Y position

Tags: android, imageview, translation

i have an imageView A that starts at right screen.
I want to set X and Y position programatically. To move the imageView near the top left corner, i have to set a X = -1497 Y = 20. What i dont understand is why X = -1497. I think because it tooks the (0,0) position where the imageView starts, but how to catch the (0,0) at top left screen?

This is because, for all screen i have to calculate a % to move the imageView to same place always, but how to do it with negative values.

```
Point origImagePos = new Point(-1460, 20);

public void moveImageView(View view){
  ObjectAnimator objectX;
  ObjectAnimator objectY;
  AnimatorSet animatorXY;

  objectX = ObjectAnimator.offFloat(view, "translationX", origImagePos.x);
  objectY = ObjectAnimator.offFloat(view, "translationY", origImagePos.y);
  animatorXY.playTogether(objectX, objectY);
  animatorXY.setDuration(500);
  animatorXY.start();
}
```

Greets

Comment: Pls post your imageView translation code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

translationX works relative to view. Try this,

```
objectX = ObjectAnimator.offFloat(view, "X", 20);
objectY = ObjectAnimator.offFloat(view, "Y", 20);
```

Comment: Welcome. translation works relative to view and this option often more useful. Imagine that you need to move view 20dp left. If you do this with "X", you have to know screen with and position of view. But you do this "translationX" you just write 20dp as a parameter and boom :) Let's say you want to move your view previous location, using "translationX" with 0 is enough to do this. In conclusion, they are just different :)

Comment: Thanks!
But now i have a problem before i dont have. im moving 2 imageView, I want one of them always be at background, but the seocnd i move always is at the front!

Comment: Put background imageView above of the other imageView at layout file. This should solve your problem.

Comment: That soluion dont work because, the first and the second imageView can change order

Comment: try view.bringToFront(); in your moveImageView(View view) method;

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could cut most your code using [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) instead of ObjectAnimator.

```
public void moveImageView(View view){

    view.animate().translationX(0).translationY(0).setDuration(500);

}
```

thats all the code you need and should move your View to the top left corner.

You could always enhance your method for later animations like this for example  :

```
// You should also always use Interpolators for more realistic motion.

public void moveImageView(View view, float toX, float toY, int duration){

     view.animate()
        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
        .translationX(toX)
        .translationY(toY)
        .setDuration(duration);
}
```

and then call it like :

```
moveImageView(yourImageView, 0, 0, 500);
```

To get the coordinates of the device dynamically so you know where to move   :

```
float screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
float screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

screenWidth + screenHeight would be the coordinates of the right bottom corner.

Top Left corner coordinates are simply 0, 0.

Center of screen coordiantes are logically (screenWidth / 2) + (screenHeight / 2).

Hope that makes your life easier in the future.